# Does robobrowser prevent types of HTML element submsisions?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib, robobrowser

I have downloaded robobrowser to assist me in logging into a webpage for web scraping.

I understand the process, but I'm having an issue when accessing form elements.

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
url1 = "example_url"

username = "example_user"
password = "example_pass"

browser.open(url1)

form = browser.get_forms()
form['username'] = username
```

There appears to be only one form and when I tried an example converting it to a string, it appeared to be finding the form. For some reason it doesn't show up as a variable in the spyder workspace unless i convert to a string.

I looked at the html and the name as well as the id for the username entry is indeed 'username'. I get the error

```
form['username'] = username
       TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

It does not accept trying to access the index in form by 'username', however this is the syntax in all of the examples for this module that i've seen.

Comment: try `print form`. I guess `browser.get_forms()` returns a list. Also the answer uses `get_form()`.

Comment: As `get_forms()` (with an s) indicates you don't get one form, but a list of forms. You have to extract the form you need from the list.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using login and password directly in the url. Here is the scheme:

```
http://USERNAME:PASSWORD@example.com/
```